# Dynamical Mean Field Theory (DMFT) does not take into account spacial correlations?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, approximations, correlation-functions, strong-correlated

It is often said that the Dynamical Mean Field Theory (DMFT) does not take into account spacial correlations. What does this mean in layman terms?

Does that mean that we assume:
$$
\langle n_i n_j \rangle - \langle n_i \rangle \langle n_j \rangle = 0
$$
where $i \neq j$ and $n_i = a_i^\dagger a_i$? Or does it mean something else?

Comment: If I recall correctly, I believe DMFT is a sort of impurity solver. This means that you have one site that is coupled to everything else. So in a sense you only get the local solution of that particular site, not the neighboring ones ("no spatial correlations"). You may also get a better answer if you post this question to https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KFGauss not quite. DMFT is better posed as a "Hubbard model solver" that in the end assumes a local [or orbital-dependent, but k-independent] self-energy. It uses an impurity solver as one of the steps.

Comment: Worth noting that one can use small clusters of sites rather than a single site with a bath, and therefore recover some of the spatial structure: https://www.cond-mat.de/events/correl18/manuscripts/potthoff.pdf

Answer (score 1):

DMFT assumes that the self-energy $\Sigma_{nn'}(\omega, k)$, which is the correction to the noninteracting Green's function $G^{-1} = G_0^{-1} - \Sigma$, is local, meaning $\Sigma_{nn'}(\omega, k) = \Sigma_{nn'}(\omega)$.

This is an exact result for the Hubbard model in the limit of infinite coordination number (nearest neighbors). Hence, DMFT is more useful for 3D (especially of high coordination number lattices), which perhaps is why it's one of the most common post-DFT methods out there.

DMFT solves the Hubbard model by decoupling the lattice into sites with strong correlation, each interacting with a mutual bath; the bath's parameters are determined self-consistently. There are a few derivations out there for DMFT. It can be thought of as a dynamical extension to Density Functional Theory, in the sense that your auxiliary potential is now time-dependent, allowing for a description of excited/equilibrium states. It's not quite a 1-1 analogy, but close enough if you don't plan on being a DMFT practitioner.